# OnResponse volley con 2 array json ! (Web service-android)

Tags: android, array, webservice, volley

estoy utilizando un web service para traer datos de 1 persona en especial. y esa persona tiene otra tabla con sus problemas en una base de datos. 
EJ:

Tabla 1: 
id nombre apellido 
1  Juan   Garcia

Tabla 2 
id idUser problema
3  1      Se me rompio algo

Lo que hago con el web service es traer 2 array json. El de usuario y el los problemas de usuarios. El php anda espectacular y todo el codigo tambien si nada mas llamo al usuario. Pero cuando intento traer los problemas tambien me compila pero me tira que "no responde"..

El problema para mi esta en el onResponse que solo pasa 1 objetojson por parametros. Me preguntaba como hacer para traer 2 array json en una sola llamada a un webservice. Vuelvo a repetir. El código anda porque cuando utilizo 1 solo array funciona. Mi pregunta es como hacer para utilizar los 2 arrays.

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment implements Response.Listener<JSONObject>, Response.ErrorListener {

EditText username, password;
Button btn;
ProgressDialog progreso;
RequestQueue request, request2;

JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
    username = (EditText)vista.findViewById(R.id.input_username);
    password = (EditText)vista.findViewById(R.id.input_password);
    btn = (Button)vista.findViewById(R.id.btn_login);

    request = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            cargarWebService();
        }
    });

    return vista;
}

private void cargarWebService() {
    progreso = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
    progreso.setMessage("Comprobando datos...");
    progreso.onBackPressed();
    progreso.show();
    String url = "http://192.168.96.1/webservice/login.php?username="+username.getText().toString()+"&password="+password.getText().toString();
    jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, this,this);
    request.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}

@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    progreso.hide();
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Datos erroneos. Por favor intente nuevamente "+error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.i("ERROR", error.toString());
}

@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    progreso.hide();
    Usuario miUsuario = new Usuario();
    problema problema = new problema();
    JSONArray json = response.optJSONArray("usuario");
    JSONArray json2 = response.optJSONArray("problems");
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    JSONObject jsonObject1 = null;
    try {

        //Problemas del usuario...
        jsonObject1=json2.getJSONObject(0); //OBTIENE EL INDEX 0. PERO SI SON VARIOS TENDRIA QUE HACER UN FOR. PRIMERO PROBAMOS CON ESTO.
        problema.setSpecialty(jsonObject1.optString("specialty"));
        problema.setDescription(jsonObject1.optString("description"));
       // problema.setFechaIngreso(jsonObject1.optString("created_at"));



        //Datos personales del usuario luego de loguearse. Lo pasamos a la vista userpanel.
        jsonObject=json.getJSONObject(0);
        miUsuario.setId(jsonObject.optString("id"));
        miUsuario.setName(jsonObject.optString("name"));
        miUsuario.setLastName(jsonObject.optString("lastName"));
        miUsuario.setEmail(jsonObject.optString("email"));
        miUsuario.setPhone(jsonObject.optString("phone"));
        miUsuario.setZone(jsonObject.optString("zone"));
       // miUsuario.setDate(jsonObject.optString("date"));


        //Enviando datos por intent hacia la ventanan de userpanel.
        Intent intent = new Intent (getActivity(), userPanel.class);
        intent.putExtra("name", miUsuario.getName());
        intent.putExtra("lastName", miUsuario.getLastName());
        intent.putExtra("email", miUsuario.getEmail());
        intent.putExtra("phone", miUsuario.getPhone());
        intent.putExtra("zone", miUsuario.getZone());
        intent.putExtra("date", miUsuario.getDate());
        intent.putExtra("specialty", problema.getSpecialty());
        intent.putExtra("description", problema.getDescription());
        //intent.putExtra("fecha", problema.getFechaIngreso());
        getActivity().startActivity(intent);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Tienes que hacerlo al revés. Adaptar el código del lado del servidor para que te traiga un solo JSON con toda la información. De hecho, ese es el sentido de las bases de datos relacionales. Tu consulta SQL debería unir `JOIN` las dos tablas y producir un solo resultado, no dos.

Comment: Lo que pasa que 1 usuario puede no tener problemas. o tener 1 o mas

Comment: Eso no importa. El JSON puede tener una clave `problemas` y dentro un array con cada problema o nada. Luego en Android verificarás si el JSON viene o no con esa clave y listar los problemas o hacer lo que necesites. Estamos ante un problema de estructuración de datos que como lo resuelvas mediocremente se notará en rendimiento de tu app, tanto en el servidor como en Android mismo. Repito debes construir un JSON que represente la información completa de la persona.

Comment: Yo pensé que esa era la peor solución. Pero bueno si usted dice, probaré. Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¡Cómo va a ser la peor! Tienes que pensar que estamos hablando de Programación Orientada a Objetos, significa que debes pensar a la persona como una entidad completa con todos sus componentes. Incluso si usas librerías como `GSON` puedes tener una clase `Persona` y mapear el JSON a esa clase de una forma muy fácil. Si los problemas son una propiedad de `Persona` deben ser parte constitutiva de ella, no algo aparte. Eso complica el código y te hace escribir programas difíciles de mantener y mucho más lentos. Lo mismo a nivel de base de datos, debes relacionar las tablas.

Comment: Sisi, las tablas estan todas relacionadas. Pero por ahí pensaba que era mejor traer 2 json. Bueno pruebo y te digo como salió. Gracias