# Como consultar 2 array con Volley

Tags: android, volley

Tengo el siguiente problema: Quiero que en un solo onResponse pueda traer dos array que tengo en un archivo PHP que he creado en un server de pruebas.

Pero cuando quiero trabajar el segundo array me dice que esta vació y la App se traba y cierra.

Tengo esto

```
// Funcion para consultar todas las Brigadas en server remoto
private void descargarBrigadas(){
    String url = "https://www.simcrs.org.sv/OCHOA/apiRestOCHOA";
    jrq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, this, this);
    rq.add(jrq);
}
```

Esa dirección tiene 2 array juntos uno que llamo brigadas, 15 registros y el otro array que llamo turnos que básicamente tiene un registro por cada dia del año, ahorita tiene como 90

Luego tengo esto

```
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    // Objeto AdminSQLiteOpenHelper
    AdminSQLite adminsql = new AdminSQLite(getActivity(), "ochoa", null, 1);
    // Abrir Base en modo lectura/escritura
    SQLiteDatabase DBM = adminsql.getWritableDatabase();
    // Borramos todo lo de las tablas Brigadas y Turnos
    DBM.delete("brigada",null,null);
    DBM.delete("turno",null,null);

    //Creamos objeto de la clase Brigadas
    Brigadas brigadas = new Brigadas();

    // brigadas se llama mi array en el server
    JSONArray jsonArrayBrigadas = response.optJSONArray("brigadas");
    JSONObject jsonObjectBrigadas = null;

    // Resgistros del array
    int arrayBrigadasLenght = jsonArrayBrigadas.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayBrigadasLenght; i++){
        try {
            jsonObjectBrigadas = jsonArrayBrigadas.getJSONObject(i);
            brigadas.setBrigada(jsonObjectBrigadas.optInt("brigada"));
            brigadas.setJefe(jsonObjectBrigadas.optString("jefe"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Variables para mostrar
        int brigada = brigadas.getBrigada();
        String jefe = brigadas.getJefe();

        // Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Brigada: " + brigada + ", Jefe: " + jefe, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        ContentValues registro = new ContentValues();
        registro.put("brigada", brigada);
        registro.put("jefe", jefe);

        DBM.insert("brigada", null, registro);
    }
    DBM.close();
}
```

Ahí voy al server remoto, traigo el array y lo inserto en mi tabla, hasta ahí todo bien.

El problema inicio cuando quiero hacer lo mismo con el 2do array y me dice que el JSONArray jsonArrayTurnos = response.optJSONArray("turnos"); es null y se crashea la app

```
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    // Objeto AdminSQLiteOpenHelper
    AdminSQLite adminsql = new AdminSQLite(getActivity(), "ochoa", null, 1);
    // Abrir Base en modo lectura/escritura
    SQLiteDatabase DBM = adminsql.getWritableDatabase();
    // Borramos todo lo de las tablas Brigadas y Turnos
    DBM.delete("brigada",null,null);
    DBM.delete("turno",null,null);

    //Creamos objeto de la clase Brigadas
    Brigadas brigadas = new Brigadas();

    // brigadas se llama mi array en el server
    JSONArray jsonArrayBrigadas = response.optJSONArray("brigadas");
    JSONObject jsonObjectBrigadas = null;

    // Resgistros del array
    int arrayBrigadasLenght = jsonArrayBrigadas.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayBrigadasLenght; i++){
        try {
            jsonObjectBrigadas = jsonArrayBrigadas.getJSONObject(i);
            brigadas.setBrigada(jsonObjectBrigadas.optInt("brigada"));
            brigadas.setJefe(jsonObjectBrigadas.optString("jefe"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Variables para mostrar
        int brigada = brigadas.getBrigada();
        String jefe = brigadas.getJefe();

        // Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Brigada: " + brigada + ", Jefe: " + jefe, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        ContentValues registro = new ContentValues();
        registro.put("brigada", brigada);
        registro.put("jefe", jefe);

        DBM.insert("brigada", null, registro);
    }

    // Creamos objeto de la clase Turnos
    Turnos turnos = new Turnos();

    // turnos se llama mi array en el server
    JSONArray jsonArrayTurnos = response.optJSONArray("turnos");
    JSONObject jsonObjectTurnos = null;
    // Resgistros del array
    int arrayTurnosLenght = jsonArrayTurnos.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayTurnosLenght; i++){
        try {
            jsonObjectTurnos = jsonArrayTurnos.getJSONObject(i);
            turnos.setFecha(jsonObjectTurnos.optString("fecha"));
            turnos.setBrigadaTurno(jsonObjectTurnos.optInt("brigada"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Variables para mostrar
        String fecha = turnos.getFecha();
        int brigadaTurno = turnos.getBrigadaTurno();

         Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Brigada: " + brigadaTurno + ", Fecha: " + fecha, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //ContentValues registro = new ContentValues();
        //registro.put("fecha", fecha);
        //registro.put("brigada", brigadaTurno);

        //DBM.insert("turno", null, registro);
    }
    DBM.close();
}
```

Busque info de como hacerlo y me tope con dos únicos sitios

[Sitio 1, el cual adapte pero no pude traer ningun dato](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43716965/how-to-call-json-object-from-two-arrays-using-volley)

[Sitio 2, el que tiene casi que mi mismo problema pero no hubo solución.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/203097/onresponse-volley-con-2-array-json-web-service-android) En este sitio le piden que haga un solo array pero no se si se aplica a mi pues yo tengo en un array 15 registros y en el otro muchisimos mas.

Les pido de favor su ayuda de como seria la mejor manera de poder descargar ambos arrays para poder continuar con mi proyecto.

Gracias

Comment: El json que retorna tú servidor es un json inválido, tal vez por eso sea el error puedes verificar tú json en http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/.

Comment: Pues a mi me arma el JSON bien ese sitio, quizás con las pruebas le había cambiado algo, pruebe ahorita por favor

Comment: Si, ahora lo construye correctamente, ¿te sigue sin funcionar tú programa posterior a éstos cambios?

Comment: Agrega a la pregunta cómo está devolviendo el JSON para poder decirte cómo tiene que ser leído, pues todo depende de eso.

Comment: Agrego todo el JSON ??? son varias lineas...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes intentarlo de esta forma:

```
// Los datos que te recibes del Servidor es en JsonArray
JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_TEST, null,
        new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                try {
                    // Acceder al Indice 0 del JSONObject para Brigadas
                    JSONObject jsonObjectBrigadas = response.getJSONObject(0);
                    // Acceder al JSONArray "brigadas"
                    JSONArray jsonArrayBrigadas = jsonObjectBrigadas.getJSONArray("brigadas");
                    Log.d(TAG,String.valueOf(jsonArrayBrigadas));

                    //Recorrer los datos del arreglo
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrayBrigadas.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject jsonObjectBrigadas1 = jsonArrayBrigadas.getJSONObject(i);
                        int brigada = (jsonObjectBrigadas1.getInt("brigada"));
                        String jefe = (jsonObjectBrigadas1.getString("jefe"));

                        // Mostrar la Informacion de las Brigadas
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Brigada: " + brigada + ", Jefe: " + jefe, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    // Acceder al Indice 1 del JSONObject para los Turnos
                    JSONObject jsonObjectTurnos = response.getJSONObject(1);
                    // Acceder al JSONArray "turnos"
                    JSONArray jsonArrayTurnos = jsonObjectTurnos.getJSONArray("turnos");
                    Log.d(TAG,String.valueOf(jsonArrayTurnos));

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrayTurnos.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject jsonObjectTurnos_2 = jsonArrayTurnos.getJSONObject(i);
                        String fecha = (jsonObjectTurnos_2.getString("fecha"));
                        int brigadaTurno = (jsonObjectTurnos_2.getInt("brigada"));

                        // Mostrar la Informacion de los Turnos
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Brigada: " + brigadaTurno + ", Fecha: " + fecha, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});

jsonArrayRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
        MY_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT,
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest);
```

Espero te sirva, saludos.

Comment: La linea (JSONObject jsonObjectBrigadas = response.getJSONObject(0);) solo acepta String en el parámetro, desde ahi ya no funciona su solución, aun le tengo fe, pero necesito saber como solventar ese impase.

Comment: @OCHOA se me hace raro porque ya hice un test y funciona correctamente con el JSON que genera la URL.

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/b2ncwMq/5.png vea esa imagen

Comment: En la linea 57 de tu codigo no estas recibiendo un Objeto, si no un Array, replica el ejemplo que le coloque como respuesta.

Comment: Tiene toda la razón, siempre estuve recibiendo un objeto (al inicio de la clase, en el método de consulta y en el onResponse), y cuando recibo el array entonces lo trabajo como usted indica. Ya veo en los Toast los dos array, eso significa que puedo hacer los insert y pasar al siguiente nivel. 
Gracias, mi app es una donación para la Cruz Roja de El Salvador, créame que me ha ayudado mucho. Es mi primer app :-(
Mañana haré los insert y si es positivo daré como resuelto el tema.

Comment: Me da gusto que te ha servido de ayuda, y éxito en tu aplicación. Puedes marcar como correcta la respuesta [Leer más](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Ps si el api esta bien en el try catch yo lo uso así solo es acceder el nombre del array q necesites, Por EJEMPLO :

```
try {
                JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray array1 =jsonObject.getJSONArray("data"); //especificas el array q necesitas acceder
                for (int i=0; i<array.length(); i++ ){
                    JSONObject ob = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    List_Data_Trends listData=new List_Data_Trends(ob.getString(("id"))
                            ,ob.getString("row1")
                            ,ob.getString("row2")
                            ,ob.getString("row3"));


                }
             JSONArray array2 =jsonObject.getJSONArray("data2");
                for (int i=0; i<array.length(); i++ ){
                    JSONObject ob = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    List_Data_Trends listData=new List_Data_Trends(ob.getString(("id"))
                            ,ob.getString("row1")
                            ,ob.getString("row2")
                            ,ob.getString("row3"));


                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

}

Comment: Pero eso ya lo hago, ahora meta un segundo array ahí por favor.

Porque lo he intentado de muchas maneras desde hace 3 días y nada :(

Comment: y como llega el response ?

Comment: Exactamente como se debe responder a esa pregunta? Pongo el array ?

Comment: el Log de response algo  como Log.d("myresponse", response.toString());

Comment: No sale nada, pero en el Toast que puse de onErrorResponse me dice: "com.android.volley.ParseError:org.json.JSONException: Value" y muestra todo el array del API

Comment: Gracias a usted tambien, aprendí lo que son y para que sirven los mensajes log.